# Click on Add auto number incerment 1,2,3-----

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th><b>ADD</b></th>
    <tr><td class = "tdCustom" ><apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addBatch}" id="update"    </td></tr>
    <td class = "tdCustom" style="width:100px;">          
    <apex:repeat value="{!batchMap[qliRow]}" var="child" id="therepeat2">
    <table class="table-data" border = "1">
    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="batchrowNum"/>
    <tr id="tr_clone">                                     
    <td> <apex:input value="0" id="counter"/></td>
    <td>
    <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteBatch}" />
    </td></tr>
    <apex:variable var="batchrowNum" value="{!batchrowNum+ 1}"/>
    </table>
    </apex:repeat>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/> 
    </apex:repeat> 
    </apex:repeat> 
    </table>
```

Sample script:i tried

```
<script>
var val;
$("#update").click(function()
{
   val = $('#counter').val();
   val++;
   $('#counter').prop('value',val )
});
</script>
```

I have one table "main table" and "sub table"(table inside maintable) while clicking on `action="{!addBatch}"` it is adding row on sub table.

If i have three items in main table i can see three add buttons .whatever add button i clicked it has to increment one number in `<apex:input value="0" id="counter"/>`

In the same when i deleting some child row in middle it has to rearrange number `<apex:input value="0" id="counter"/>`

Comment: __IDs must be unique in HTML__ Why can't you use class selector?

Comment: paste your code on fiddle it is best to identify